# Nagios doesn't take the python output

Tags: python, linux, centos, nagios

I'm doing a script in python to take the disk write/read speed in a minimal CentOS 7 to use it as a Nagios plugin and display the information on the Nagios Server, it's already done and if i run it on the client machine (the one that gives the information about the disk speed) it gives the right output but when the Nagios server checks for that service, it always takes the UNKNOWN option

Write disk speed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

disk_speed=os.popen("dd if=/dev/zero of=./tempfile bs=1M count=1024 2>&1 | awk '/copiados/{print $8, $9}'").read()
disk_speed2=os.popen("dd if=/dev/zero of=./tempfile bs=1M count=1024 2>&1 | awk '/copiados/{print $8}'").read()

if "GB" in disk_speed:
        print "OK - the write disk speed is %s" % disk_speed
        sys.exit(0)
elif "MB" in disk_speed and (disk_speed2 >"750" and disk_speed2 <= "999"):
        print "WARNING - the write disk speed is %s" % disk_speed
        sys.exit(1)
elif "MB" in disk_speed and (disk_speed2 > "0" and disk_speed2 <= "750"):
        print "CRITICAL - write the disk speed is %s" % disk_speed
        sys.exit(2)
else:
        print "UNKNOWN write speed"
        sys.exit(3)
```

Read disk speed:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

disk_speed=os.popen("dd if=./tempfile of=/dev/null bs=4k 2>&1 | awk '/copiados/{print $8, $9}'").read()

disk_speed2=os.popen("dd if=./tempfile of=/dev/null bs=4k 2>&1 | awk '/copiados/{print $8}'").read()

if "GB" in disk_speed:
        print "OK - the read disk speed is %s" % disk_speed
        sys.exit(0)
elif "MB" in disk_speed and (disk_speed2 >= "850" and disk_speed2 <= "999"):
        print "WARNING - the read disk speed is %s" % disk_speed
        sys.exit(1)
elif "MB" in disk_speed and (disk_speed2 > "0" and disk_speed2 < "850"):
        print "CRITICAL - read the disk speed is %s" % disk_speed
        sys.exit(2)
else:
        print "UKNOWN read disk speed"
        sys.exit(3)
```

Hope you can help me on this one, it would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Just run the bare dd command on the command line. I guess the output is probably not in Spanish, so the expected word "copiados" is not matched by awk. If this is the case, setting LC_ALL should help.

Comment: It's in spanish, as i said if run it on the command line i get the expected output but not with nrpe

Comment: Then it should be checked, it nrpe does not change the locale. Could you try the script with the English word "copied" ?

Comment: It gives error if i try it with 'copied' because the dd command output it's in spanish because it's the language used on the system. I think it does not has to do with language

Comment: Then my guess was wrong. I'm sorry to waste your time. Capturing the script output would still help a lot.

Comment: No problem, thank you for taking the time to answer this. I'll keep trying

Comment: When Nagios runs the script, where does it write the ./tempfile ?

Comment: Log into your Nagios server, and try running the command - something like: ./check_nrpe -H <host> -C <nrpe_command_name>  ... what is the entire output?